# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'some name to data type int.

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

When i run my entire query I am getting this error message:

```
------------------------------------
--POPULATE SECTIONAAVGTAT-----------
------------------------------------
;with SpecimenDetail as (
select
s.*
,a.[mlis id]
,a.director
,a.rm
,a.rep
,a.css
,a.css2
,dbo.networkdays(s.[date received],GETDATE())-1 [Days On Hold]
,(case when dbo.networkdays(s.[date received],GETDATE())-1>=7 then '7+' 
   when dbo.networkdays(s.[date received],GETDATE())-1 in (5,6) then '5-6'
   when dbo.networkdays(s.[date received],GETDATE())-1 in (3,4) then '3-4'
   when dbo.networkdays(s.[date received],GETDATE())-1 in (1,2) then '1-2'
   when dbo.networkdays(s.[date received],GETDATE())-1=0 then '0'
  else 'na'
end) as [Days on Hold Group]
 from specimendetailtmp s
left join sectionaalignment a
on s.[mlis practice id]=a.[mlis id]
where s.[date distributed] is not null
and s.[date received]>='20121112'
and s.sectiona='not marked'
)


,

AvgTAT as
(
select 'director' emptype,director employee, cast(round(AVG(cast (dbo.networkdays(s.[date received],s.[date distributed])-1  as float)), 3, 1) as decimal(10,1)) AvgTAT,month(s.[date received]) month from SpecimenDetail s
where s.[date distributed] is not null
group by director,month(s.[date received])


union all

select 'rm' emptype,rm employee, cast(round(AVG(cast (dbo.networkdays(s.[date received],s.[date distributed])-1  as float)), 3, 1) as decimal(10,1))AvgTAT,month(s.[date received]) month from SpecimenDetail s
where s.[date distributed] is not null
group by rm,month(s.[date received])

union all

select 'rep' emptype,rep employee,cast(round(AVG(cast (dbo.networkdays(s.[date received],s.[date distributed])-1 as float)), 3, 1) as decimal(10,1)) AvgTAT,month(s.[date received]) month from SpecimenDetail s
where s.[date distributed] is not null
group by rep,month(s.[date received])

union all

select 'css' emptype,css employee,cast(round(AVG(cast (dbo.networkdays(s.[date received],s.[date distributed])-1  as float)), 3, 1) as decimal(10,1)) AvgTAT,month(s.[date received]) month from SpecimenDetail s
where s.[date distributed] is not null
group by css,month(s.[date received])

union all

select 'css2' emptype,css2 employee,cast(round(AVG(cast (dbo.networkdays(s.[date received],s.[date distributed])-1  as float)), 3, 1) as decimal(10,1)) AvgTAT,month(s.[date received]) month from SpecimenDetail s
where s.[date distributed] is not null
group by css2,month(s.[date received])
)

select * from avgtat
```

however if i run any of the inner selects, everything works fine!

**why am i getting this error only when i execute the entire script?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that one or more of the `SELECT` clauses in the `UNION ALL` segments is producing results that implicitly convert to `int`.  And, the other `SELECT` clauses return results that are `nvarchar`.  The implicit conversion can occur when column values in the results are all integers.

If you don't know which column is causing the problem, you should review the results of each `SELECT` and determine if there's a common pattern (e.g., all values are integers in a nvarchar column.)  Then, when you know the column that's generating the problem, use `CAST` or `CONVERT` to explicitly cast the value to the desired data type.

Comment: thanks so much! but i dont even know which column it is referencing!

Comment: You can start by removing columns from the common table expression that are not used.  And, temporarily remove columns from the `UNION ALL` queries until the error disappears.  The last column removed is the one that causes the problem.